# Mounted docker.sock login not stored

Tags: docker, docker-registry, gitlab-ci

I'm using gitlab CI runner to build a docker image and I want to push it to my private registry.
The CI runner is using `docker:latest` and I mounted `/var/run/docker.sock` into the container.

The `docker login -u myuser -p mypass registry.mydomain.com:5000` works and it says login succeeded, but when I try to push the built image in the next command I get `unauthorized: authentication required`.

Where does docker store the login to a registry? Is it even possible to push to a custom registry having a docker container, that mounts to hosts `docker.sock`.

Steps to reproduce:

```
docker run -ti -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock docker sh
docker login -u username -p password registry.myhost.com:5000
docker build -t registry.myhost.com:5000/namespace/user:latest .
docker push registry.myhost.com:5000/namespace/user:latest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker stores login tokens to the registries at:

```
${HOME}/.docker/config.json
```

If you're running all of your commands as a single script from the same user, then perhaps there's a restrictive proxy or firewall, or the private registry is misconfigured in some way.

Comment: Yes I just figured out, that my private registry user was configured read only. Thx for the hint